# Issue with target frameworks of ScintillaNET and Winforms application

Tags: .net, winforms, scintilla

I have to work with a rather complex winforms application which is targeted towards .net framework 3.5. Changing the application or its target framework is not recommended. I can create plugins, which are loaded from a DLL when the application starts, to add new functionality.

I would like to use ScintillaNET (which is targeted towards 4.0) in such a plugin.  Is that possible?

Generally put, is there a way to access a DLL targeted towards 4.0 from a dll that is targeted towards framework 3.5?

Maybe something similar to hosting WPF inside Winforms?

Is there another way? Maybe there is a stable Scintilla release targeted to framework 3.5 I haven't discovered?

Answer (score 1):

You can try ScintillaNET 2.6. It targets .net Framework 2.0 but it's no longer mantained (lastest stable version dates back to 2014): https://scintillanet.codeplex.com/releases/view/118666